# typescript - propagating selected type of a union type in inner function

Tags: typescript, generics

```
const func = <T>(
  x: string | ArrayLike<T>
) => (y: string | ArrayLike<T>, at = 0) => {
  // do stuff with x and y
}

const temp = func ('abc')
```

In that example temp is casted as : `(y: string | ArrayLike<string>, at? number) => void`
But what i'm looking for is for temp to casted as `(y: string, at? number) => void`, and as such respecting the type of `x` passed to `func` which was a string.

Furthermore i guess i understand why the generic type `T` is casted as string - but for what I want i need **either a ArrayLike of T or a string** and not a mix of the two...

I need it in order to simplify the returns type of a call to temp.

Any help is more than welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an overloaded function:

```
function func(x: string): (y: string) => void;
function func<T>(x: ArrayLike<T>): (y: ArrayLike<T>) => void;
function func<T>(x: string | ArrayLike<T>) { 
  return (y: string | ArrayLike<T>, at = 0) => {
    // do stuff with x and y
  };
}

const temp = func('abc')  // (y: string) => void
```

This will give you the correct types for calls to `func`, though the implementation of `func` still has to deal with the union types.

Comment: Thanks a lot! waiting a bit if someone comes up with a Extract solution, and if not i'll validate you're answer